# Merge all Shabbat tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tag-synonyms, merge-tag-request

Can we please **merge** all of the shabbat tags (or at least make them all synonyms of each other)?

List that I know of so far:

- [shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat)
- [leil-shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leil-shabbat)
- [oneg-shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oneg-shabbat)

Answer (score 4):

A tag search for "shabbat" (the only way I can think of for somebody to easily get to most of the Shabbat questions) currently shows the following:

- [shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat): 341
- [shabbat-songs](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat-songs): 33
- [challah-shabbat-bread](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/challah-shabbat-bread): 20
- [leil-shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leil-shabbat): 13
- [yom-shabbaton](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yom-shabbaton): 3
- [oneg-shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oneg-shabbat): 2
- [kabbalat-shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kabbalat-shabbat): (no number shown, 1 use)
- [shabbat-yomtov](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat-yomtov): (no number shown, 341 uses - synonym for shabbat, I presume)

If we want to sub-divide questions about Shabbat, this doesn't appear to be an effective way to do it.  People will just go to the 341 and miss the 13 and 2 that motivated this question.

What we *really* need is hierarchical tags, so that we could tag specifically but register them all to also show up under shabbat.  I don't know of a way to do that in SE.  So I think if we're going to keep the sub-tags like oneg-shabbat that we *also* need to always tag those questions [shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat) for findability.  The tag wiki for [shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat) should link to all the others (including ones that don't happen to have "shabbat" in their names, which my search missed), so that people looking for a more-specific needle in that haystack will have some starting points.

Comment: I think [tag:evening-night] is a better second tag than [tag:leil-shabbat] because it can be used as a tag elsewhere, and people can always search for questions with both tags.

Comment: MonicaCellio, see http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1267.

Answer (score 2):

[Monica Cellio's answer](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1159) seems to have the support of the community (judging by votes). To summarize it, we should split [shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat) into multiple tags, link in the tag wikis from the former to each of the latter and vice versa, and (and this is mainly where it differs from [msh210's answer](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1157)) require the [shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat) tag on any question that has one of the finer tags.

Very well, what split?

I'm making this a community-wiki answer so people can chime in with how the [shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat) tag should be split. What should the finer tags be? Edit the following at will, and indicate an estimate of how many questions each tag could have. Also indicate if the tag does not yet exist.

- [oneg-shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oneg-shabbat) (wiki should say it's also for questions about *oneg yom tov*) *currently has 2 questions; perhaps get rid of it?*
- [shabbat-meals](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat-meals) (nonexistent as of now) (merge most of [leil-shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leil-shabbat) into here)
- [shabbat-songs](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat-songs) *currently has 34 questions, plus 3 tagged* [yom-shabbaton](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yom-shabbaton) *for a total of 37*
- [erev-shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/erev-shabbat) (wiki should say it's also for questions equally about *erev Shabas* and *erev yom tov*)
- [challa-shabbat-bread](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/challa-shabbat-bread) (note its synonym [lechem-mishneh](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lechem-mishneh))
- [melacha-creative-work](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/melacha-creative-work)
- [muktzeh](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/muktzeh)
- [shabbat-prayers](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat-prayers) (nonexistent as of now)
- [shevut](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shevut) (nonexistent as of now; wiki should describe *hachana*, *chafatzecha*, etc.; would need good synonyms and possibly a better name)
- [kiddush](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kiddush)
- [eruv-carrying](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eruv-carrying), a merger of [eruv-chatzerot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eruv-chatzerot) and [hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot)
- <del>*shabbat-electricity* or</del> [technology-on-shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology-on-shabbat) (nonexistent as of now)

Comment: leil-shabbat has 4 questions, all about the home ritual (3 could be meals and 1 songs).  I would remove that one.  (And will, but I'm leaving a trail in comments.)

Comment: erev-shabbat doesn't seem especially coherent to me but I'm not yet sure how I would retag those 3 questions.

Comment: eruv-chatzerot and hotzaa-carrying-reshuot are the same topic and should be collapsed into one.  I would call it eruv-carrying and make the existing ones synonyms.

Comment: @MonicaCellio re:[tag:erev-shabbat] There would be more than 3 questions, but I stopped msh210 from retagging them and rather start this discussion. So it might still end up being a valuable category. Someone just has to go count.

Comment: @DoubleAA, thanks.  I didn't see the chat discussion until after I'd made these comments.  I'll remove my strike-through.

Comment: @All: If you're gonna strike through a tag, rewrite it not using `[tag:`, because strikethroughs don't show on tags displayed using `[tag:` (or at least not in some browsers).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we should merge [leil-shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leil-shabbat) into [shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat), because the former has enough questions and enough independent interest (IMO) to keep it as a separate tag. I do think each tag's description should link to the other's.

I'm not expressing in this answer my opinion about [oneg-shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oneg-shabbat).